# GMaps Geocoding from PHP Value

Tags: php, api, google-maps, geocoding

I'm having some problems trying to figure out how to generate a Google Map from an address sent by POST or GET data from another page.

I want to have it so the map shows up right away, and doesn't need to be triggered by someone inputting an address in an input box.

If anyone has some resources that could help me figure this out, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need Javascript as well as PHP. See below link on S/O

[Passing address to Google Maps on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157750/passing-address-to-google-maps-on-page-load)

Comment: In the original question on that link, don't forget to add single quotes around <?php echo $gmap; ?> i.e. '<?php echo $gmap; ?>' and you should be fine.