# Address in PHP variable, Google Maps embedding without Javascript?

Tags: php, google-maps, geocoding

I consider myself to be an average PHP coder, but I can barely edit the few bits of JavaScript code that I need on my websites. I have an address in a PHP variable and I would like a simple map to show up on my webpage with that address. I've done some research on the internet and I find a lot op geocoding, converting an address to a location the Google API understands, but I'm completely lost. Is there no simple piece of code to in which I can embed my variables?

Comment: Check this question out, it should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157750/passing-address-to-google-maps-on-page-load

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use an iframe and pass the address as an URL parameter.

```
<iframe width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.it/maps?q=<?php echo $yourAddress; ?>&output=embed"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Awesome solution without complex javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use the [Geocoder API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en-US#Geocoder).

Here you go ( original can be found [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple?hl=en-US) ) :

```
<head>
...
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12, //Change the Zoom level to suit your needs
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    //map_canvas is just a <div> on the page with the id="map_canvas"
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    //Your Variable Containing The Address
    var address = "<?php echo $AddressVariable; ?>"; 
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        //places a marker on every location
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });

  }

</script>
...
</head>
```

Add this to the opening `body` tag of your page to initialize the map:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

And [here's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en-US#Geocoder) the documentation for the `Geocoder` class.

Answer (score 1):

Updated code - an API key is required nowadays. You may need to urlencode the address but it should even work without it:

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY
    &q=<?php echo $address; ?>" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-started

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<?php 
 $address = str_replace(" ", "+",$address_variable);
?>
<iframe style="width:100%;height:50%;" frameborder="0" id="cusmap" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.it/maps?q=<?php echo $address; ?>&output=embed"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another example:

```
<div class="container rounded border shadow-sm info-property mt-4 pt-4 pl-5 pr-5 pb-2 bg-white">
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h6 class="info-property-title">Mapa:</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" 
                src="https://maps.google.it/maps?q=<?php echo $map_address; ?>&output=embed"
                frameborder="0" 
                style="border:0;" 
                allowfullscreen="" 
                aria-hidden="false" 
                tabindex="0"
                scrolling="no" 
                marginheight="0" 
                marginwidth="0"
                >
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Embedding a Gmap**

Different type of modes for google map: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/embedding-map
[image: here]

**Choosing map modes**

You can specify one of the following map modes to use in your request URL:

1. **place**: displays a map pin at a particular place or address, such as
   a landmark, business, geographic feature, or town.
2. **view**: returns a map with no markers or directions.
3. **directions**: displays the path between two or more specified points
   on the map, as well as the distance and travel time.
4. **streetview**: shows interactive panoramic views from designated
   locations.
5. **search**: shows results for a search across the visible map region.

   ```
    <div id="maps"></div>

        $(document).ready(function() {   
           var key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
           var lat = '54.320889726653014';
           var lon = '-130.30591155093268';
           var addr = '<?php echo sanitize($restaurant_details['address']); ?>';  
           var width = 350;
           var height = 350;    

           var embed= "<iframe width='"+width+"' height='"+height+"' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0'src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key="+key+"&zoom=18&center="+lat+","+lon+"'></iframe>";

       $('#maps').html(embed);
   });
   ```

Answer (score -1):

These links are use full to you..not the exact link but its use full :) tc..

1)[remove-address-bubble-from-google-maps-iframe](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/remove-address-bubble-from-google-maps-iframe/)

2) [google maps](http://tulsawebresults.com/how-to-hide-the-info-bubble-in-a-google-map)